# What game system should I use for a new campaign: familiarity or abundant material

Tags: pathfinder-1e, game-recommendation, fantasycraft

After a couple of decades away from RPGs, I've have been a player for several months with a steady group playing FantasyCraft.  Meanwhile, I've been preparing a campaign of my own and done a lot of system-agnostic research, note taking, and world preparation.  All high level stuff for the beginning, middle, and end of the story I intend to create with the players.  I intend to fill in a lot of the spaces between with pre-gen adventures I have in mind.

Now I have to decide on implementing the setting using FantasyCraft mechanics or Pathfinder mechanics.

FC comes with familiarity, but I'll have to do conversion of existing material I want to use.  That could be a lot of work.  The one thing I've *not* done in FC is conversion (being a player).

Using Pathfinder I get the material for free, but may have to do some house-rulings for things I've [heard](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-to-mitigate-glass-cannon-syndrome-in-pathfinder) are [broken](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?p=14536851) but seem improved in FC.  Also, I'll need to figure out what supplemental stuff to include/exclude.  Wrt Pathfinder, I've been listening to podcasts, read a good bit of the core rulebook, looked through some third party material, and have been reading about it so I know something of the game, just no practical play experience.

**So, given the choice, would you opt for game mechanics you are more familiar with or for which there is more material?**

Comment: Without knowing more about your group, any answer to this would be pure opinion.  Please consider how to make this question have a right/best answer especially given [our game-rec guidance on Meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1071/760).

Comment: @mxyzplk The question is more about my own time and effort and not about what is best for my group.  Would it be better characterized as a level of effort when converting?

Comment: Sure, whatever the specific requirements are you are judging against, besides "which is better." Also the kind of game you and your group play. If you are rules wonks then obviously the answer skews harder than if you're more story driven.