# What to do if I roll an overpowered character?

Tags: adnd-2e, powergaming

Recently my friend decided to start making an AD&D 2e campaign and told my 3 friends and I to roll characters. My friends rolled their character and got pretty average stats but when I roll it way above average. I ended up rolling a 18/91% str, 17 dex, 17 con, 17 int, 14 wis and 11 chr. At first I was super excited to play this character but the more I think about it I don't want to ruin my friends campaign. He was super upset with my stats, plus the fact I'm using a large bastard sword doesn't help. I don't want to end up taking the spot light in all the combat encounter and skill check encounters, I want everyone to have an equal amount of fun. Is there any tips you could give me?

Comment: So, why dont you just reroll?

Comment: just out of curiosity, what was your rolling method? (Helps understand how 'out of line' your rolls were with expectation.)

Comment: we were doing the method roll 4d6 and remove the lowest number.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/22173/what-to-do-when-your-character-is-just-too-good

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I want everyone to have an equal amount of fun

The roll of the dice has nothing to do with that desire.

You don't need to re-roll this character.  You can adopt the role of the "strong supportive type" and by *your play* not overshadow the other players.  You won't ruin their fun if *you* don't play in an overbearing manner, nor will you ruin the campaign.  The dice don't dictate how you play your character.    Your focus? Be a good team player.

There will be some scenarios where having that really strong guy will be good for the party, particularly at low levels.  As you all level up together, the initial differential will tend to even out as other players' skill and spells increase with level.

Bottom line: don't assume that you have to be ruled by a die roll.  Play the character in a way that you are a benefit to the team and be a good team player.  Having awesome stats does not prevent you from fitting into the team.

** Note: I got my start in OD&D and 1e AD&D, where it was common for us to have very different luck with the dice.  None of that kept us from playing as a team: we tried to get the most out of each players' talents and contribute to a team success.  The "we all start with equal luck" approach to D&D has some merit, but it isn't necessary for the game to be fun.

Comment: Thank you so much, that outlook of the game helps me a alot!

Comment: Best wishes and happy gaming!